# Coherent States of Coupled Oscillators

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises

I am given the following coupled Hamiltonian
$$H=\hbar\omega[a_x^\dagger a_x+a_y^\dagger a_y+1+K(a_x^\dagger a_y+a_y^\dagger a_x)]$$
Which I can decouple into two different oscillators
$$H_u=\frac 12 \hbar \omega(1+K)(a_u^\dagger a_u+1)$$
$$H_v=\frac 12 \hbar \omega(1-K)(a_v^\dagger a_v+1)$$
I am then given that the system is prepared in a state $|\psi(0)\rangle=|0\rangle_x|\alpha(0)\rangle_y$ is a coherent state such that 
$$\langle\psi(0)|y|\psi(0)\rangle=y_0$$
$$\langle\psi(0)|p_y|\psi(0)\rangle=0$$
I find that 
$$\alpha(0)=y_0\sqrt{\frac{m\omega}{2\hbar}}$$
Finally, I am asked to show that each of the oscillators is in a coherent state for all time and that $\langle x(t)\rangle$ and $\langle y(t)\rangle$ act as coupled classical oscillators.  I am not sure how to show that they act as coherent states.  Showing the expectation values seems simple enough once I can find x and y as functions of time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prove your answer in two steps.

1. Show that the initial state is a (tensor product of) coherent state for the new oscillator modes i.e., it is also an eigen vector of both $a_u$ and $a_v$.
2. Next, show that any coherent state continues to remain a coherent state under time evolution, possibly with a time-dependent $\alpha$, where $\alpha$ is the parameter associated with the coherent state.

You are done.

Comment: And the initial state was that $|0\rangle_x|\alpha(0)\rangle_y$.  So I act the u and v operators to make sure I get them back?

Comment: Yes! You should show that $a_u |\psi(0)\rangle = \alpha_u|\psi(0)\rangle $ and $a_v |\psi(0)\rangle = \alpha_v|\psi(0)\rangle $ for some constants $\alpha_u$ and $\alpha_v$.

Comment: So I have been trying this.  I have that $a_u=(a_x+a_y)$ so $a_u|\psi(0)\rangle=a_x|0\rangle_x|\alpha(0)\rangle_y + a_y|0\rangle_x|\alpha(0)\rangle_y$.  I believe that the $a_x$ will eliminate the zero state, but can I figure what $a_y|\alpha(0)\rangle_y$ is?

Comment: Ah. So you don't know that coherent states are eigenstates of the annihilation operator. Well, they can be defined as follows: $a\ |\alpha\rangle = \alpha\ |\alpha\rangle$, where $\alpha$ is any complex number. $\alpha=0$ corresponds to the ground state of the SHO.

Comment: I know that from your answer.  I am just wondering if I can say that $a_y$ on the x state will be ignored.

Comment: Since you are working in the tensor product of two Hilbert spaces (call them $X$ and $Y$), the operator $a_y$ is best thought of as acting as unity on the $X$ space and $a_y$ on the $Y$ space. The fancy way is to say that is  $1\otimes a_y$ acts on $X\otimes Y$. Similarly, $a_x$ is written as $a_x\otimes 1$. So $a_x$ give zero while $a_y$ gives $\alpha(0)$ times the initial state.

Comment: Awesome!  Additionally, to show that the expectation of x and y behave like classical coupled oscillators, do I have to find the position x in terms of the u and v operators?

Comment: Yes, that is all that is needed.